# How to create a Daemon application in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I am a newbie. Can anyone please help me how to create a daemon application in Cocoa ? Went through the resources here but m not able to understand properly. Have been struck here since 2 days. Should the application be a foundation tool? Should the code be written in C? How should I implement 'launchd'? I won't find any complete tutor for this? Please help me out . . . .

Answer (score 6):

Creating daemons and agents is covered in [Apple’s Technical Note TN2083](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Should the application be a foundation tool?

Yes

> Should the code be written in C?

You can use C, Objective-C, or a mix of the two.

> How should I implement 'launchd'? I won't find any complete tutor for this?

Try [this one](http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/all_about_launchd_items_and_how_to_make_one_yourself).

There's also [this](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) GUI for launchd configuration.