# what's the counterpart of a Windows service on Mac OSX

Tags: windows, macos, service

On Windows, we call something running at background as service. What about on Max OSX, is there such thing? what is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re called agents or daemons. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6097819/557219).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the closest analog is a `launchd` service.
Launchd is Apple's replacement for `init` and `cron`, among others.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd